# Log Drive Full Due to ReportServer Database Growing

Tags: sql, transaction-log, reportserver

I have a report server log file that is 100 million kb.  The report server was set to full recovery with no transaction log backup configure.  I added a Tlog backup which should truncate the file over time.  But the sql logs drive is completely full.  How do I free up space or shrink it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to shrink your log (and don't care what's inside, no log shipping etc.) you can use DBCC command:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE(<log_file_name_Log>)
BACKUP LOG <database> WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY
DBCC SHRINKFILE(<log_file_name_Log>)
```

Also, set the recovery mode to simple before shrink.

IMPORTANT: THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDED PRACTICE, use it only if you don't need your log file.

In the future, set SQL Agent to backup log periodically, it will keep your log size reasonable.